# Send an Object data vit GET with AngularJS error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm having a problem with my GET request to API, here is:

```
self.search = {
  init_date: new Date(),
  end_date: new Date(),
  statuses: {"Aberto": false, "Em andamento": false, "Fechado": false},
  district: null,
  address: null,
  tags: null
};

$http.get(apiUrl + requestEndpoint + 'search', {params: self.search}).then(function(response){
  self.gridOptions.data = response.data;
});
```

So, what is happening is that my params in API looks like this

```
{"end_date"=>"2016-07-07T22:58:11.943Z",
 "init_date"=>"2016-07-07T22:58:11.943Z",
 "statuses"=>"{\"Aberto\":false,\"Em andamento\":false,\"Fechado\":false}",
 "format"=>:json,
 "controller"=>"api/v1/requests",
 "action"=>"search"}
```

and then I cannot read the `statuses` because it's a kind of string. How should I solve that?

Just to know... My Statuses value come from form in HTML with checkboxes

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h5>Status</h5>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="aberto" class="k-checkbox" value="Aberto" ng-model="reportsCtrl.search.statuses['Aberto']">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="aberto"> Aberto </label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="em-andamento" class="k-checkbox" value="Em andamento" ng-model="reportsCtrl.search.statuses['Em andamento']">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="em-andamento"> Em andamento </label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="status" id="fechado" class="k-checkbox" value="Fechado" ng-model="reportsCtrl.search.statuses['Fechado']">
        <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="fechado"> Fechado </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: My API is Rails

Regards.

Comment: why use GET and not POST?

Comment: It is a view for a report. So I send data to API like status of request that I want and range of dates, to get this for my report... It's not correct send a GET request?

Comment: With complex objects might be easier using post. Otherwise you need to json decode `statuses`

Comment: It's may have to do with Content-type in request-headers? When I send as $http.get I don't have a Content-Type in my headers.

Comment: There is no content type for a GET... all the data is in url

Comment: Like: ?foo=bar$etc=tal

Comment: That's what `$http.get()` will do...yes. In order to pass your array it is parsing to json

Comment: I understand... so, my problem was that I was using wrong method for my needs. Thank you very much